# How to update formulas in a number of cells based on number reference from adjacent cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file displaying sale locations on a physical floor. These cells are formulated to display various indexes by returning values from another sheet ; adjacent to these locations is a position number ranging from 1 to 250 that can be to the left, above, to the right or below the location. I am looking for the most optimized way to update the formulas in the locations cells based on the position number filled into the adjacent cell so for example if position changes from 2 to 3 when running a macro the location formula should change from =TOTALS!$V$11 to =TOTALS!$V$12 where $V$12 comes from position 3+9 rows..

I can provide sample file

Tried Interior.ColorIndex, R1C1 formulas etc.

Started with identifying the colors did not get to the formula part.

```
Sub Test1()

'white is -4142
'pink color index 38
'green  color index 10
'red color index 3
'turcoise color index 8
'yellow color index 6
'blue color index 5
'purple color index 13

Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select

Range(Left(Selection.Address, InStr(Selection.Address, ":") - 1)).Interior.ColorIndex


For Each possValue In Selection

    If Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 5 Or Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 38 Then
        If Left(Selection.Offset(0, -1).Address, InStr(Selection.Offset(0, -1).Address, ":") - 1).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 And Left(Selection.Offset(0, -1).Address, InStr(Selection.Offset(0, -1).Address, ":") - 1).HasFormula = False Then

            MsgBox Left(Selection.Offset(0, -1).Address, InStr(Selection.Offset(0, -1).Address, ":") - 1).Value

        End If

    End If

Next possValue

End Sub
```

I have a file displaying sale locations on a physical floor. These cells are formulated to display various indexes by returning values from another sheet ; adjacent to these locations is a position number ranging from 1 to 250 that can be to the left, above, to the right or below the location. I am looking for the most optimized way to update the formulas in the locations cells based on the position number filled into the adjacent cell so for example if position changes from 2 to 3 when running a macro the location formula should change from =TOTALS!$V$11 to =TOTALS!$V$12 where $V$12 comes from position 3+9 rows..

[image]

Comment: Asking for *the most optimized way* would make this question Too Broad, leading to closure, though may be more appropriate for another site like Code Review (they help optimize code which does run).  Can you update your question to relate to the code you've provided, as there should be many ways to get to what you're asking (though I'm honestly a bit confused in your explanation of the data for what it looks like you're asking)?

Comment: How can I update question?

Comment: On the bottom of your post there are buttons for "share", "edit", and "flag"... click edit.  you should be able to search for the word "edit" using ctrl+f if need be.